# Tensorflow issue with own retrained graph in java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm having a small issue with tf on java. I retrained my model for new categories with python (1.8.0 version) and I'm trying to recognise the images with Java ( Intellij, Maven project, Tensorflow version 1.1.0) i'm getting the following error.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](module_apply_default/hub_input/Sub, module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).`

I changed the tf version in Maven to 1.8.0 so to be the same with the python version and then I got this

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [DecodeJpeg/contents] in the Graph
```

Line in code: `Tensor result = s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents", image).fetch("softmax").run().get(0)) {
h`

When i'm using a pretrained inception model graph from dec 2015 and not mine everything is working smoothly without errors. Does anybody knows what happening here and how can I fix that? I would be really thankful for any answers :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error messages, this is what I gather:

- Using 1.8.0 to create the model but 1.1.0 to load the model fails with the `Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.` error because the graph being saved by the 1.8.0 binary  uses features not in 1.1.0. So you should have your Java program be using the same or later version of TensorFlow as the binary that produced the graph.
- The second error message suggests that the name of the input tensor in your model is different than the one in the pre-trained model. You'd want to replace the string `DecodeJpeg/contents` in your Java program with the appropriate name. Hard to say what it would be since it would depend on the details of your program. However, if you can figure out the name of the tensor you'd provide to the `feed_dict` argument for `Session.run` in Python, then that's what you'd provide in Java.

Hope that helps.